# Transaction count error after execution of SQL procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I am passing `boost::uuids::uuid` object from C++ code to the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteOption]
    @featureOptionId VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
    
    DECLARE @InUse tinyint = 5;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OptionsSet WHERE FeatureOptionID = @featureOptionId)
                DELETE FROM FeatureOptions WHERE FeatureOptionID = @featureOptionId
        RETURN @InUse
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
GO
```

I am getting the following error:

> Odbc_Command::ExcecuteDone(): ExecDirect() failed! {? = CALL
> DeleteOption( ? )} SqlState=25000 NativeError=266
> ErrorMsg=[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number
> of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

I don't know if I did syntax error or logical error. Also I am not sure about `@featureOptionId`'s type, but I searched in the web and it seems that it suits me.

Comment: Maybe is it because I may return from the transaction without committing it?

Comment: It seems you are mixing up Procedures and Functions. A stored procedure should not have a return statement. Try doing a  SELECT @InUse instead.

Comment: featureOptionID should also be specified and an IN and InUse should also be specified as an OUT.